# apache access log exclude static files like css|js|png|gif etc

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I want to reduce the size of my Apache access log and needs to exclude static files from logging like js|css|xml|png|gif & more.

I am parsing access log to track user activity & website data.

I have tried DonNotLog apache directive but didn't work, may be some configuration issue with my code:(

My Apache configurations were --

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(jpg|css)" DontLog

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u \"%{%s}t\" %D \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{username}n %{sessionID}n" vhost_combined DontLog
```

Comment: Generally speaking it is appreciated if you actually post what you have tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `SetEnvIf` and logging directives. Example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.gif$|\.jpg$" is_static
```

sets all URIs ending in .gif or .jpg to have the environment variable "is_static".

```
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!is_static
```

means that everything that does not have the is_static environment variable will be written to access_log in the common format.

Extending the regexp in the SetEnvIf directive to cover all file types you want is left as an exercise for the reader...